# python class import issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and doing some programming for school I have written code for a roster system and I am supposed to use dictionaries. I keep getting error No module named 'players_Class'
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

```
class Players:

    def __init__(self, name, number, jersey):
        self.__name = name
        self.__number = number
        self.__jersey = jersey

    def setname(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def setnumber(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def setjersey(self, jersey):
        self.__jersey = jersey

    def getname(self):
        return self.__name

    def getnumber(self):
        return self.__number

    def getjersey(self):
        return self.__jersey

    def displayData(self):
        print("")
        print("Player Information ")
        print("------------------------")
        print("Name:", self.__name)
        print("Phone Number:", self.__number)
        print("Jersey Number:", self.__jersey)

    import players_Class

def displayMenu():
        print("1. Display Players")
        print("2. Add Player")
        print("3. Remove Player")
        print("4. Edit Player")
        print("9. Exit Program")
        print("")
        return int(input("Selection> "))

def printPlayers(players):
    if len(players) == 0:
            print("Player not in List.")
    else:

        for x in players.keys():

            players[x].displayData(self)

def addplayers(players):

        newName = input("Enter new Players Name: ")

        newNumber = int(input("Players Phone Number: "))

        newJersey = input("Players Jersey Number: ")
        players[newName] = (newName, newNumber, newJersey)
        return players

def removeplayers(players):
    removeName = input("Enter Player Name to be removed: ")
    if removeName in players:
        del players[removeName]
    else:
        print("Player not found in list.")
        return players

def editplayers(players):


    oldName = input("Enter the Name of the Player you want to edit: ")

    if oldName in players:

        newName = input("Enter the player new name: ")

        newNumber = int(input("Players New Number: "))

        newJersey = input("Players New Jersey Number: ")

        players[oldName] = petClass.Pet(newName, newNumber, newJersey)

    else:

        print("Player Not Found")

        return players



print("Welcome to the Team Manager")

players = {}

menuSelection = displayMenu()


while menuSelection != 9:

    if menuSelection == 1:

        printPlayers(players)

    elif menuSelection == 2:

        players = addplayers(players)

    elif menuSelection == 3:

        players = removeplayers(players)

    elif menuSelection == 4:

        players = editplayers(players)

    menuSelection = displayMenu()

print ("Exiting Program...")
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where did you get the  import players_Class? Since you are using only one file, no import required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have unused

```
import players_Class
```

statement in your code. just erase it!

Comment: well, your code includes some other errors, like for example line: players[newName] = (newName, newNumber, newJersey),  players[x].displayData(self) ... are wrong. But this errors are not connected to the primary question. Use debugger and fix the code step by step.